# Export data from GridView to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I have `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView;`
I can save all the data from it in Excel using the method

```
gridView.ExportToXls(fileDialog.FileName);
```

but I need to not just save the data from it but add footer as well.

For example:

```
any text string, date and other text

column1 column2 column3 ...
data     data    data   ...
data     data    data   ...
...       ...    ...    ...
```

Code:

```
public void Export(GridView gridView)
{
    try
    {
        SaveFileDialog fileDialog = GetFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            gridView.ExportToXls(fileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "nodobavit footer." ?

Comment: I need to start adding some text document

Comment: ok, Can you also provide your code which you had tried ? It will be more useful.

Comment: You are using web application or MVC ? Please provide grid design also.

Comment: DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView;

Comment: Now I have everything working. but occurs only export data grid. I also need to add their data to the document.

Comment: That is fine but please provide your grid view design file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know how to do (((that is exactly what you need to show

Comment: Bind Only Data Which you want in excel or create new page with required data and export it form there..

Comment: Can you show aspx code here ?